# discord.js role created but not with information

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently in the process of writing a function that will create a new user role, assign a random colour & Name that role after the user who issued the command. The code is as follows:

```
            message.guild.createRole({
              data: {
                name: 'Super Cool People',
                color: 'BLUE',
              },
              reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
            })
              .then(console.log)
              .catch(console.error);
```

Which as some of you may be aware, it's directly out of the documentation for the CreateRole. However, the issues i'm encountering is that it's successfully creating a role, but the name of the role is "new role" as opposed to the name specified above & The color of the role is unaffected by this. Logs show:

```
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133373+00:00 app[worker.1]: id: '700481043597099059',
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133373+00:00 app[worker.1]: name: 'new role',
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133374+00:00 app[worker.1]: color: 0,
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133374+00:00 app[worker.1]: hoist: false,
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133374+00:00 app[worker.1]: position: 1,
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133374+00:00 app[worker.1]: permissions: 104324673,
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133374+00:00 app[worker.1]: managed: false,
2020-04-16T23:01:35.133374+00:00 app[worker.1]: mentionable: false
```

Permissions are defaults, nothing special going on here. Users who will have access to this command will already have sufficient permissions assigned from a higher ordered role. However, the problem lays that the specific role is not named as intended & No colors are assigned.    using message.guild.createRole seems to fit within the boundaries i'm using as it's in the message await async call. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be simple, you can randomise the colour by using `RANDOM` as the value and you can use the GuildMember's username for the role

```js
message.guild.createRole({
                name: message.author.username,
                color: 'RANDOM',
            })
              .then(console.log)
              .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This provides no solution to the question above. The new role name is coming up default "new_role" and no color assigned - Despite having the data field in play, no obvious errors are being logged either

Comment: I just fixed my answer, it should work now, your issue is that you're using discord.js v11 but you're following the structure of discord.js v12's role creator.